An unusual use of reflection principle to construct a function in Rudin's RCA 16.20 before the proof of Little Picard Theorem
Rudin's reasoning:
16.18 A Subgroup
We shall take for $\Gamma$ the group generated by $\mid \sigma$ and $\tau$, where
$$
\sigma(z)=\frac{z}{2 z+1}, \quad \tau(z)=z+2
$$
One of our objectives is the construction of a certain function $\lambda$ which is invariant under $\Gamma$ and which leads to a quick proof of the Picard theorem. Actually, it is the mapping properties of $\lambda$ which are important in this proof, not its invariance, and a quicker construction (using just the Riemann mapping theorem and the reflection principle) can be given. But it is instructive to study the action of $\Gamma$ on $\Pi^{+}$, in geometric terms, and we shall proceed along this route.
Let $Q$ be the set of all $z$ which satisfy the following four conditions, where $z=x+i y:$
$$
y>0, \quad-1 \leq x<1, \quad|2 z+1| \geq 1, \quad|2 z-1|>1
$$
$Q$ is bounded by the vertical lines $x=-1$ and $x=1$ and is bounded below by two semicircles of radius $\frac{1}{2}$, with centers at $-\frac{1}{2}$ and at $\frac{1}{2} \cdot Q$ contains those of its boundary points which lie in the left half of $\Pi^{+} . Q$ contains no point of the real axis.
16.19 Theorem
Let $\Gamma$ and $Q$ be as above.
(a) If $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2 \in \Gamma$ and $\varphi_1 \neq \varphi_2$, then $\varphi_1(Q) \cap \varphi_2(Q)=\varnothing$.
(b) $\bigcup_{\varphi \in \Gamma} \varphi(Q)=\Pi^{+}$.
(c) $\Gamma$ contains all transformations $\varphi \in G$ of the form
$$
\varphi(z)=\frac{a z+b}{c z+d}
$$
for which $a$ and $d$ are odd integers, $b$ and $c$ are even.
16.20 Theorem
If $\Gamma$ and $Q$ are as described in Sec. 16.18, there exists a function $\lambda \in H\left(\Pi^{+}\right)$such that
(a) $\lambda \circ \varphi=\lambda$ for every $\varphi \in \Gamma$.
(b) $\lambda$ is one-to-one on $Q$.
(c) The range $\Omega$ of $\lambda$ [which is the same as $\lambda(Q)$, by (a)], is the region consisting of all complex numbers different from 0 and 1.
(d) $\lambda$ has the real axis as its natural boundary.
Proof. Let $Q_0$ be the right half of $Q$. More precisely, $Q_0$ consists of all $z \in \mathrm{II}^{+}$such that
$$
0<\operatorname{Re} z<1, \quad|2 z-1|>1
$$
By Theorem 14.19 (and Remarks 14.20) there is a continuous function $h$ on $\bar{Q}_0$ which is one-to-one on $\bar{Q}_0$ and holomorphic in $Q_0$, such that $h\left(Q_0\right)=\Pi^{+}$, $h(0)=0, h(1)=1$, and $h(\infty)=\infty$. The reflection principle (Theorem 11.14) shows that the formula
$$
h(-x+i y)=\overline{h(x+i y)}
$$
extends $h$ to a continuous function on the closure $\bar{Q}$ of $Q$ which is a conformal mapping of the interior of $Q$ onto the complex plane minus the nonnegative real axis. We also see that $h$ is one-to-one on $Q$, that $h(Q)$ is the region $\Omega$ described in ( $c$ ), that
$$
h(-1+i y)=h(1+i y)=h(\tau(-1+i y)) \quad(0<y<\infty)
$$
and that
$$
h\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} e^{i \theta}\right)=h\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} e^{i(\pi-\theta)}\right)=h\left(\sigma\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} e^{i \theta}\right)\right) \quad(0<\theta<\pi)
$$
Since $h$ is real on the boundary of $Q$, (3) and (4) follow from (2) and the definitions of $\sigma$ and $\tau$.
11.14 Theorem (The Schwarz reflection principle)
Suppose L is a segment of the real axis, $\Omega^{+}$is a region in $\Pi^{+}$, and every $t \in L$ is the center of an open disc $D_t$ such that $\Pi^{+} \cap D_t$ lies in $\Omega^{+}$. Let $\Omega^{-}$be the reflection of $\Omega^{+}$:
$$
\Omega^{-}=\left\{z: \bar{z} \in \Omega^{+}\right\}
$$
Suppose $f=u+i v$ is holomorphic in $\Omega^{+}$, and
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} v\left(z_n\right)=0
$$
for every sequence $\left\{z_n\right\}$ in $\Omega^{+}$which converges to a point of $L$.
Then there is a function $F$, holomorphic in $\Omega^{+} \cup L \cup \Omega^{-}$, such that $F(z)=f(z)$ in $\Omega^{+}$; this $F$ satisfies the relation
$$
F(\bar{z})=\overline{F(z)} \quad\left(z \in \Omega^{+} \cup L \cup \Omega^{-}\right)
$$
The theorem asserts that $f$ can be extended to a function which is holomorphic in a region symmetric with respect to the real axis, and (3) states that $F$ preserves this symmetry. Note that the continuity hypothesis (2) is merely imposed on the imaginary part of $f$.
My question:
How does Rudin use the reflection principle to get a function that seems to use the symmetry of the y-axis instead of the x-axis?

Basically, what you're really after in the reflection principle are the roles of the real line, conjugation in the parameter space and conjugation in the image space. They are special but not that special, in the sense that you only want their geometric properties. Let me explain what I mean in more detail:
We are in a situation where we have an open set $\Omega_0^+ \subset \mathbb{C}$, a segment $L_0$ of an axis $\Gamma_0 = e^{i\theta_0} \mathbb{R}$ such that, in the connected component $\Pi_0^+$ of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \Gamma_0$ containing $\Omega_0^+$, all $t \in L_0$ are the centers of disks $D_t$ such that $\Pi_0^+ \cap D_t \subset \Omega_0^+$.
We also have a holomorphic function $g : \Omega_0^+ \to \mathbb{C}$, such that $g(z) \to \alpha_t \in \Gamma_1$ when $z \to t \in L$ for some common axis $\Gamma_1 = e^{i\theta_1} \mathbb{R}$ of $\mathbb{C}$.
Now, call $\sigma_0$ and $\sigma_1$ the respective symmetries about the axes $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$, that is:
$$\sigma_j(z) = e^{i\theta_j} \overline{e^{-i\theta_j} z} = e^{2i\theta_j} \bar z$$ (see for yourself why that is the case geometrically).
What we'll have is the following conclusion:

Reflection principle for general axes: in the context described above, and setting $\Omega_0^- := \sigma_0(\Omega_0^+)$, we can extend $g$ to a holomorphic function $G$ on $\Omega_0^+ \cup L_0 \cup \Omega_0^-$ satisfying the relation:
$$\forall z \in \Omega_0^+ \cup L_0 \cup \Omega_0^-,\quad G(\sigma_0(z)) = \sigma_1(G(z))$$

Proof: it's actually fairly simple. What we want to do is apply the known version of the reflection principle to the right function related to $g$.
Geometrically and intuitively, all we have to do is therefore to rotate the parameter space and the image space so that $\mathbb{R}$ is rotated onto $\Gamma_0$ to apply $g$ to the parameters and then rotate $\Gamma_1$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ so that the images are also in the correct position.
To do so, define $\Omega^+ := e^{-i\theta_0} \Omega_0^+$, $L := e^{-i\theta_0}L_0$, and: $$f : z \in \Omega^+ \,\longmapsto\, e^{-i\theta_1}\left(g(e^{i\theta_0} z)\right) \in \mathbb{C}$$
$f$ is holomorphic because $g$ is, and satisfies $f(z) \to e^{-i\theta_1}\alpha_t \in e^{-i\theta_1}\Gamma_1 = \mathbb{R}$ for $z \to e^{-i\theta_0}t \in e^{-i\theta_0}L_0 = L$, meaning that we can apply the known version of the reflection principle.
We can thus extend $f$ into a holomorphic function $F : \Omega^+ \cup L \cup \Omega^-$ such that:
$$\forall z \in \Omega^+ \cup L \cup \Omega^-,\quad F(\bar{z}) = \overline{F(z)}$$
At this point, we can then let: $$G : w \in \Omega_0^+ \cup L_0 \cup \Omega_0^- \,\longmapsto\, e^{i\theta_1} F\left(e^{-i\theta_0} w\right)$$
$G$ extends $g$ because $F$ extends $f$, $G$ is holomorphic because $F$ is, and:
$$\begin{split} G(\sigma_0(w)) &= G\left(e^{i\theta_0} \overline{e^{-i\theta_0}w}\right)\\
&= e^{i\theta_1} F\left(\overline{e^{-i\theta_0} w}\right)\\
&= e^{i\theta_1} \overline{F\left(e^{-i\theta_0} w\right)}\\
&= e^{i\theta_1} \overline{e^{-i\theta_1} \left[e^{i\theta_1}F\left(e^{-i\theta_0} w\right)\right]}\\
&= \sigma_1\left(e^{i\theta_1}F\left(e^{-i\theta_0}w\right)\right) = \sigma_1(G(w))\end{split}$$
$\square$
Notice also how I took axes passing by the origin, when you can see that we could totally adapt the context and the proof to even more general axes by simply adding or substracting constants.
